# Is possible to join two tables (One Mysql, the other Oracle) from two different servers in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, join

I'll spare the back story, but basically I have two different databases that I retrieve information from. 1 being Oracle (which we've only been given read-only access to) and the other being Mysql (which we have full access to). My problem is there is column in the oracle table that is missing that we would like to pull data from, however that column we need is in the mysql table. Is there a way that I can write a join statement to include this mysql column to the oracle table? I've seen instances online where people have used 'LinkedServers', but I wasn't sure how that worked working in PHP. The DB connections are stored in a php file and the function is called when we want to use that particular database.

tl;dr

Can a user use a join for a mysql and oracle table? if so, how can it be implemented in php when the db info is in a separate php file?

I imagine the sql query would look similar to this:

```
select
    *
from
    LocalTable,
    [OtherServerName].[OtherDB].[dbo].[OtherTable]
```

but with some join logic

Comment: could you copy across the core Oracle data into a quick MySQL table/database and the Join MySQL db/table 2 MySQL db/table ?

Comment: @Martin I have considered taking the data from Oracle and creating a table in Mysql with that data, but I think the issue with that would be the possibility of new data getting pushed to the Oracle database. I would never get it since it would be a copy.

Comment: surely where the data is pulled from doesn't effect where the data is saved to, that's a code issue not a DB storage issue.

Comment: @Martin I must have misunderstood you. I thought you meant creating a snapshot of the sql data. Could you go more in depth with what you mean?

Comment: grab all the data from the Oracle database and put it into a MySQL database, then do your original operation between two MySQL databases, or even 1 database with two sets, so the imported data the tables are all pre-empted with `import_<tablename>` etc.

Comment: @Martin So are you implying I do a .sql dump and then import to MySQL?

Comment: yes, you'll need to do some search and replace on the SQL dump with a notepad++ or similar code/text editor and all the table names append `_import` but then you can import the data into your destination MySQL table and that makes working with it much, Much easier.

Comment: @Martin but what happens if new rows are added to the oracle table, or data is changed. Does that mean I'll have to do another .SQL dump?

Comment: hmmm, yes, your choices in that respect are limited to how often the table is updated, and if you can change the code that updates the Oracle to update your version instead / as well as ? Sorry, I was approaching this as a one-instance routine for like moving a dataset but do you want this as an ongoing system, in which case my attempted solution is not what you'd need.

Comment: @Martin No worries. Thanks for the insight. I will keep it in mind if there is no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot join 2 different database vendors.
A query is executed by a specific vendor query analyzer.

You can however do the join itself IN php, but would require to dump a lot of info into php. Should be okay for small data sets not okay for large ones...

What you would want to do is copy the data from one vendor into a temp table in the other then execute the join.

For the purpose of this example I will use PDO.
I am going to take the oracle data and put it into mysql so that I can use a join on that data...

```
$oracle_table_b = "select * from mytable";
$oracle_data = $pdo->fetchAll();
$stmt = $pdo_mysql->prepare("insert into mytemptable (mycols)");
foreach ($oracle_data as $row) {
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

//Then run your join

Comment: Ahhhh, I figured as much, but it doesnt hurt to ask. With that being said, if I dont need alot of the data, could I just run a query with just enough information I need to do the join with the temporary table? I mean, Im pretty entry level, Im not sure what is considered large; the oracle table is 1500 rows. Also, could this pose as a possible security concern?

Comment: Large as in a few hundred megabytes of data...

I don't see any way for it to be a security concern, but there really isn't enough information posted here to tell.

Comment: Ahhh I gotcha. I don't think there should be no worries there but again Ill double check. I supposed honestly it would be no different writing the query for any other thing. 

So to make sure I follow you correct. Use PHP to store my Oracle data as a Temporary table, then use my join based off that temporary table? Could you provide an example?

Comment: what is $pdo in this instance?

Comment: Is there a solution without php? For example linked servers or using odbc?